# Nakama Godot Error code Not Found when trying to auth

Tags: godot, nakama

```
extends Node

var client : NakamaClient
var session : NakamaSession
var socket : NakamaSocket
var username = "example"
var play_service


func _ready():
    if Engine.has_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices"):
        play_service = Engine.get_singleton("GodotPlayGamesServices")

        play_service.init(true, true, true, "id")
        play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_success", self, "ConnectToNakama")
        play_service.connect("_on_sign_in_failed", self, "_on_sign_in_failed")

        play_service.signIn() # <-


func _on_sign_in_failed(status:int) -> void:
    pass
func ConnectToNakama(account_id:String) -> void:
    var split = account_id.split('"')
    var id = str(split[11])
    print(id)
    print(username)
    client = Nakama.create_client('defaultkey', "ip", 7351,
    'http', 3)
    session = yield(client.authenticate_device_async(id, username), 'completed')
    if session.is_exception():
        print("connection has failed " + session.exception.message)
        return
    
    socket = Nakama.create_socket_from(client)
    yield(socket.connect_async(session), "completed")
    
    print("Connected!")
```

Server version: 3.14.0+e2df3a29
Godot version: 3.5.1

I get this error code:
DEBUG === Freeing request 1 01-15 22:52:00.542 20046 20263 I godot : === Nakama : DEBUG === Request 1 returned response code: 404, RPC code: 5, error: Not Found 01-15 22:52:00.542 20046 20263 I godot : connection has failed Not Found

I double checked evrything but I can't find the problem help much aprecciated

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue with the help of someone. You just have to change the port from 7351 to 7350 because 7351 is for admins